# What is returned from MySQL and pdo::fetchColumn() if an empty result set?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$sql='SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE x=?';
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(123));
$id=$stmt->fetchColumn();
syslog(LOG_INFO,'id ='.$id.' and is '(is_null($id)?'null':'not null'));
```

PHP `$stmt->fetchColumn()` returns what appears to be null, however, isn't when tested.

MySQL when tested at the shell indicates `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0008 sec)`.

What is `$stmt->fetchColumn()` returning for an empty result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `PHP` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php):

> Returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if there are no more rows.

For `fetching` use:

Single row fetch:

`$stmt->fetch();`

Multiple rows fetch:

```
while($stmt->fetch()) { 
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns `false`.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

By the way, I don't think `$id=$stmt->fetchColumn();` is correct as you should get an array I think.